# Select No Have / Only 1 Criteria

Tags: postgresql

I Have Some Table with Data:

| id | year | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2017 | 21 |
| 2 | 2017 | 22 |
| 1 | 2018 | 34 |
| 2 | 2018 | 55 |
| 1 | 2019 | 23 |
| 2 | 2019 | 43 |
| 3 | 2017 | 44 |

I only want to display id that have the year 2017 only, not those that already have the full year

means it only wants to display id = 3 only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to get the Id that is only associated with 1 year, and not multiple?

This can be achieved by joining laterally a grouped table by Id having 1 row, then filtering on the year you are looking for. Just replace `your_table` with the name of your table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table 
JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT id, COUNT(*)
  FROM your_table _t
  WHERE _t.id = your_table.id
  GROUP BY id
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) AS _table on true
WHERE year = 2017;
```